# How to access a function from a class?

Tags: c++, class

How do you access a function from a class, outside of that class?

**Example:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    class ImageLoading
    {

    void Loading()
    {
        cout << 5 <<endl;
    }

    };

Loading();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need an object of class to access it, or make it static and use class name

Comment: @P0W: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You've found the _comments section_, an area for critiquing, for requesting clarification, and for having fights with people. If you wish to answer the question (this means providing a solution for the question's author), the proper place for that is the _answer section_, which you may find down below. Then your answer can be peer reviewed as normal. Thank you, and enjoy the site!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought users were encouraged to not farm useless reputations since last 3 yrs and 11 months. But point noted, I always respect 200K+ users.

Comment: @P0W: Using the site correctly is not "rep-farming". Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the function of a class outside of the class requires 1 of 2 things which are:

1. An instance of the class.
2. A `static` function.

Let's talk about a class real quick.  By default when you make a `class` the default access modifier for functions or variables is `private:` meaning only the class itself can call it, there are some other classes that can access that but that is not really relevant at this time.  In the question posted the function `Loading` is private.  This means it can only be called from within the class.  Even with an instance of the class you cannot call it from `main`.

If you would like to call the function without an instance of the object it needs to be `static` and `public`.

Example using your code:

```
class ImageLoading
{
public:
    static void Loading()
    {
        cout << 5 << endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ImageLoading::Loading();

    return 0;
}
```

The downside to a `static` function, is that it doesn't belong to an instance of a class so if you have class variables that are not static, the static function cannot modify them without an instance of that object.

Here is a good source with some examples of `Access Modifiers` in c++:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access

Answer (score 3):

A standard function defined in a class is an instance class. It can be used only on an instance, i.e. a created object.
To do that, you need to create an `ImageLoading` class instance:

```
ImageLoading instance;
instance.Loading();
```

It is possible too to create functions associated to the class and not to its instances. For that, you need to add the keyword `static` in the function definition

```
static void Loading()
{
    cout << 5 << endl;
}
```

Then to use it, you need to tell that it is the static class defined in `ImageLoading`. The syntax is `ClassName::MethodName()` so:

```
ImageLoading::Loading();
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to create an instance of the class, and then call it with it.

```
ImageLoading image;

image.Loading();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class is defined outside the main method: Following is the proper way to do this:

```
  class ImageLoading
   {
     void Loading()
      {
       cout << 5 <<endl;
      }
   };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   ImageLoading Obj;
   Obj.Loading();
   return 0;
 }
```